# How to change user role using hook

Tags: user-roles, user-meta

I have created some custom user  field , so i can manage my users as dealer in my website . 
Now my problem is with that user  role , i want to make something in my function.php to check if my custom fields  are not empty  so the user role can change to Dealer ,otherwise let be a simple user .

I hope someone can help .

```
function fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3 id="dealer_button" ><?php _e(' DEALER SECTION ', 'racecar.ch'); ?></h3>
<div id="dealerpackage"></div>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="address"><?php _e('NR. OF FEATURED PACKAGE ', 'racecar.ch'); ?>
        </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="feature_package" id="feature_package" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'feature_package', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter number of featured packages.', 'Racecar.ch'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="address"><?php _e('NR. OF PREMIUM PACKAGE ', 'racecar.ch'); ?>
        </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="premium_package" id="premium_package" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'premium_package', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter number of premium packages.', 'Racecar.ch'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="address"><?php _e(' Dealer Contact URL  ', 'racecar.ch'); ?>
        </label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="dealer_url" id="dealer_url" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'dealer_url', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter the url of contact form .', 'Racecar.ch'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr> -->
</table>
```

```
   function fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return FALSE;

       update_usermeta( $user_id, 'feature_package', $_POST['feature_package'] );
       update_usermeta( $user_id, 'premium_package', $_POST['premium_package'] );
       //update_usermeta( $user_id, 'dealer_url', $_POST['dealer_url'] );

     }

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields',100 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'fb_add_custom_user_profile_fields',100);

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields',100 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'fb_save_custom_user_profile_fields',100 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit your function and add code used below for adding user role in `functions.php`

This is basic idea how roles can be added and removed and how you can check your filed values. Please use according to your requirements.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );

function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {

// here you need to update your required conditions, ie: check if meta values are set or not. I haven't checked your meta values but its supposed to like condition which is written in if condition, otherwise thr role update will work but take care of your condition

  if(get_the_author_meta( "feature_package", $user_id ) && get_the_author_meta( "premium_package", $user_id )){
     $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
     $u->set_role('author'); // please replace with your required role ie: delar 
   }else{
     $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
     $u->set_role('subscriber');
   }
}
```

[WP _User class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.2/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L29)

For more details please follow links below:

[profile_update developer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/profile_update/)

[profile_update codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update)

Just for explanation, what above code is going to do. When any user will update his profile. The condition will check if there are values set in user custom fields, then the role of user will get changed according to passed value like "author" in this example.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Jas four your reply , i tried your solution but it seems not working for me  `//I think this is how it can work for your case
        if(get_the_author_meta( "feature_package", $user_id ) && get_the_author_meta( "premium_package", $user_id )){
           $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
           $u->remove_role( 'individuals' ); // remove previous role
           $u->add_role( 'professional' ); // set your delar role 
       }`

Comment: I have updated answer, please check thats working for me.

Comment: Great ,  Thank you,is working for me now  this solution .:) .I was thinking to make something different , is there any way that i can check all users , and to change the role ,only to them Who have one of this filed fulfilled .and  if both field are empty the user role must change to 'subscriber' . Thank you for your time

Comment: Above will work if when user will edit there profile. But I think if you want to do in bulk with users for once, there will be need of script in which you can fetch all users and check required fields with above condition. And can modify if fields are  not empty  then assign particular role otherwise assign other particular role.

Comment: yes your example is working if they edit they profile .at is all right . But in my case it will be better if i check all users as you said , I don't have to much experience with bulk  .I will appreciate your help

Comment: Do you want this to run one time only ie: or there will be need of changing roles of users once in your site or that will be required again and again.

Comment: Again -again  , because this two fields can change any time .and i want to change the user role if they are fulfilled or empty

Comment: I have updated code. I think fields will only change when user edit there profiles. So now when both fields are not empty it will assign role "author" and if those are empty then it will assign role "subscriber". I think this will serve your purpose in good way.

Comment: Yes this can help, but how can i make this function not when  user update they profile .Because in my case the user do not update they profiles by her self , there is a function in my theme  that check if they make a premium post this number will decrements by one ....till it is 0 ..and if it is 0 i want to change this role to a normal user not Dealer

Comment: I think its already many comments here and also that will be different thing ie: you need to update profile of users programmatically depending on your value 1 or 0 . So I believe you can run code to update user profile from function where you are checking the things related to 0 and 1 . Thanks!